# Finding 1:1:1 reports in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database where the reporting lines of a company are stored in the format Table: managers; `Fields unique_id, user_id, manager_id`

I want to know if there are users who are in a 1:1:1 relationship, meaning one person having one boss and that boss again only one boss. It's supposed to show inefficient or wrongly recorded reporting lines. Some of the data is not correct, some people have too many reporting lines.

So I tried to do a 1:1 (left side) check first to see how many managers a user has in the table itself:

```
SELECT COUNT(managers.manager_id), managers.user_id 
FROM managers 
GROUP BY managers.user_id 
ORDER BY count(managers.manager_id) DESC
```

That works fine. I can see that there is one person on top who has a count of 5 managers: `"mananger count=5; user_id='xyxz';"`. So then I wanted to add the right :1 side by joining the table to itself but attaching the the people who consider the users as their manager:

```
SELECT COUNT(managers.manager_id), managers.user_id, COUNT(reports.user_id) 
FROM managers 
LEFT JOIN managers AS reports ON managers.user_id=reports.manager_id 
GROUP BY managers.user_id 
ORDER BY count(managers.manager_id) DESC
```

That, however shows bogus data, and on top of it it shows the same number for both counters. I know that there is a person having 308 reports and the top line of the result is now  `"manager count=308; user_id='xyxz; reports count: 308"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that joins are multiplicative, so that if a user has one manager but that manager has four managers, then the user will appear in the result four times.  In each of those results, the user's `manager_id` will be the same number—but since that number isn't `NULL`, counting it will produce 4 rather than 1.

Since neither of your counted columns are ever `NULL`, they obviously produce the same result: ∑(num_managers_managers).  If you think about it, it's hard to define what else the `COUNT(managers.manager_id)` column in your second resultset could possibly mean, especially for users who have multiple managers who each have a different number of managers of their own.

Instead, join derived tables that have been filtered using `HAVING` for only those with one manager:

```
SELECT t1.user_id    AS user,
       t1.manager_id AS boss,
       t2.manager_id AS bossboss
FROM   (
         -- users who have only one manager (and that manager's id)
         SELECT   user_id, MAX(manager_id) AS manager_id
         FROM     managers
         GROUP BY user_id
         HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
       ) AS t1 JOIN (
         -- joined back to itself
         SELECT   user_id, MAX(manager_id) AS manager_id
         FROM     managers
         GROUP BY user_id
         HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
       ) AS t2 ON t1.manager_id = t2.user_id
```

Comment: Ah, so you mean if the first example I used groups users to the user_id level, the LEFT JOIN in the second example joins them before the grouping and therefore multiplies everything. Makes sense.